# Does $20n$ belong to $O(n^{1-\epsilon})$ for some $\epsilon > 0$?

Tags: asymptotics, master-theorem

I am quite new to master theorem and I would like to ask the following question for $$()=4(/4)+20.$$
If there is a constant value like $20n$ does it affect the equation?

Would the equation look something like this for test case 1:

> Is $f(n) = 20n \in O(n^{log_ba-\epsilon}) \in O(n^{\log_4^4-\epsilon}) \in O(n^{1-\epsilon})$ for some $\epsilon > 0$?

Comment: Your question has little to do with the master theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Big O notation hides constant factors. In particular, for every constant $C > 0$,
$$
f \in O(g) \Longleftrightarrow Cf \in O(g).
$$
In particular, for any $\epsilon > 0$,
$$
20n \in O(n^{1-\epsilon}) \Longleftrightarrow n \in O(n^{1-\epsilon}).
$$

This follows directly from the definition of big O. Indeed, suppose that $f \in O(g)$. Then there exist $N,A>0$ such that $f(n) \leq Ag(n)$ for all $n \geq N$. This implies that $Cf(n) \leq ACg(n)$ for all $n \geq N$, and so $Cf = O(g)$. Similarly, if $Cf = O(g)$ then the same argument shows that $f = C^{-1} C f = O(g)$.